# Get DataGridView values and display them in a new form using a single Class

Tags: c#, winforms

The concept is simple. The user selects a row and clicks "Edit", opens the form and all the data from the row is in the perspective fields on the edit form.

I've had no problem doing this method with a ListView using SelectedItems[0].Tag, but working with a DataGridView now and I get a object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've been Googling around and it seems the only way this can be accomplished is to first get the values of the DataGridView row into a list.

So something like firstcell = part.item1, secondcell = part.item2, etc.

Finally tell it List = part;

```
    private void EditPart()
    {
        PartData part;

        // Ignore if no row is selected
        if (DgParts.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // Is not tagging data at all.
            part = (PartData) DgParts.SelectedRows[0].Tag;

            // Open Form with Data
            var edit = new FrmPartsAddEdit(this, "Edit", part);

            // Commit if OK
            if (edit.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                part = edit.GetPart();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBoxError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

DataGridView is in full row select and multi select is false.

Comment: What is the reason why you are using `Tag`? What exactly do you want to do? Read the values in the row and edit them?

Comment: @hattenn yes its always worked in ListView but I'm working with a DataGrid and there are obviously different ways to do things.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the null reference exception? As @Tergiver said, `Tag` is probably not the best solultion here, and  you have to assign it yourself. However, let's work with what you have. Have you checked `Tag` does actually contain a `PartData` object. (Or something that can be cast to a `PartData`.)

Comment: @Stainy I'm not getting a null reference, in debug it passes the part = (PartData)... but in the Locals, there is nothing contained within part.  I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the new form when it tries to associate with the controls.  Thats where I'm running into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The Tag property used throughout WinForms is not used internally. It is there for your use, should you find it useful. It has to be set to something for there to be something.

The Tag property isn't appropriate here. What you need is something that can take a DGV row and convert it to a PartData which can then be passed to your dialog ctor.

Presumably the DGV row contains (in its columns) all of the stuff that make up a PartData.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than sending `DgParts.SelectedRows[0].Tag`, just send `DgParts.SelectedRows[0]`. This will be a `DataGridViewRow`.

Then in the class that you send this `DataGridViewRow`, let's say it's called `myRow`, you can go through the elements using `myRow.Cells['column name']` or `myRow.Cells[columnIndex]`. Or you can iterate through the elements.

Another way would be to just send all the elements using `DgParts.SelectedRows[0].Cells.List`. This will send the content of the row in an `ArrayList`.

For more information check this out:

[DataGridViewRow Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Warning: VB syntax, but easy enough to convert to C#.

Assuming `PartData` is the class representing your data, you want to bind a generic list of parts - `List(Of PartData)` - to the DataGridView. Then on the `SelectionChanged` event, you can get the underlying reference to the PartData object that is selected in the List and pass that to the constructor of the edit form for editing:

```
If DgParts.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem IsNot Nothing Then

    Dim f as New EditPartForm(DgParts.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem)

End If
```

The constructor of the `EditPartForm` would take a parameter of type `PartData`.

One thing to keep in mind that binding a List(Of PartData) to a DataGridView will show one column for every property of the PartData class. You'll have to set `.Visible = False` on each column you don't want to display.